# UIImageView center not updating properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm practicing some iOS programming. I'm looking to move a UIImageView object to a given position on the screen. The storyboard contains 
-Three textboxes to input X Y and Z components (xbox,ybox,zbox)
-Three labels to display said component values (XLabel,YLabel,ZLabel)
-UIImageView containing an image (ball)
-Go button (calls buttonPressed when pressed)

The following code successfully moves the image after inputing values into the textboxes n clicking "GO". However, when I uncomment the code to update the labels, the image does not move until I click "GO" twice in a row. The first time, the labels updates. The second time, the image updates. Why does it require two clicks when I have the label update code uncommented?

Thanks,
Rob

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
       [self graph: [xbox.text intValue] :[ybox.text intValue] :[zbox.text intValue]];

    /*
     XLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X:%@", xbox.text];
    YLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Y:%@", ybox.text];
    ZLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Z:%@", zbox.text];
     */
    }
...
-(void)graph:(int)xpos : (int)ypos : (int)zpos{
    ball.center = CGPointMake(xpos,ypos);
}
```

Comment: Have you turned off AutoLayout for your storyboard? AutoLayout does not play nicely with changes to properties like bounds, center, or frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to provide this as an answer. Turn off auto-layout.